# Orchestrate Azure synapse spark notebook from C#/api

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-sdk-.net, spark-notebook

Is there a way to execute notebook from c# like an api or sdk. I found the following to create and update notebooks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/analytics.synapse.artifacts-readme-pre, nothing to trigger it like how I can submit a Spark batch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/analytics.synapse.spark-readme-pre.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try using CLI commands for [az synapse notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/notebook?view=azure-cli-latest#az_synapse_notebook_create) and [az synapse spark job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/spark/job?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: @swethaKandikonda but that not have any way to run the notebook